# select tag in form not working

Tags: html, sql, forms, html-select

I have a form and a drop-down list inside it...

```
<form method="post" action="rew1.php" id="inputform">
<select form="inputform" name="some1">
<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Travel Mode</option>
<option value="Train">Train</option>
<option value="Flight">Flight</option>
</select>
</form>
```

But when i post using this form the value Train Or Flight is not posted in to the database....
Here's The Server Side Code...

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","plsdonthack","cab");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO cabs (NAME,IDNO,HOSTEL,MODE,DATE,TIME,TFNO,CONTACT)
VALUES
('$_POST[name]','$_POST[idno]','$_POST[hostel]','$_POST[mode]','$_POST[date]','$_POST[time]','$_POST[tfno]','$_POST[contact]')";



if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

mysqli_close($con);
header("location:http://localhost\overflow\index.html");
?>
```

What is the mistake i am making....?

Comment: Why are you expecting the data from that select to be in the database?It does not have a name attribute, and you also have not shown us your server-side code.

Comment: Your code is totally susceptible to SQL injection. You should look into using MySQLI properly with placeholders to prevent this.

Comment: ya just building the framework...will get in to the details after every thing works properly....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should set name attribute for `select` like this:

```
 <select name="something">
```

Comment: what does this name attibute do exactly...?

Comment: if you don't put any name for it, server will not recognize your sent data and can't use it

Comment: it seems you don't get posted data to use and save in database

Comment: before using the select tag it was working perfectly fine....i had use a input type="text" before...i wanted to enhance readablity so i used select tag but not working any more